# Insert string of comma seperated strings in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I want to Insert `"'765','76','70','70','80','82','11'"` into `nvarchar` column in sql-server. How it's possible?

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what exactly was the problem?

Comment: Please note that we often see people putting comma-separated values into one column in SQL, and then they get all sorts of problems trying to get them out individually. There is a better way of storing the data if you are going to need the individual parts.

Comment: Seriously reconsider doing this. It's a terrible idea and violated 1NF

Comment: @AndrewMorton I have a  key-value table as config. Imagine these are codes of some info that are forbidden in filtering a query result. So I have a key to select config, and according value, in addition to Id. The Value column type is nvarchar, and in my case these codes are string to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
DECLARE @N NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @N = '''765'',''76'',''70'',''70'',''80'',''82'',''11''';
SELECT @N AS Result;
```

Result:

```
+-------------------------------------+
|               Result                |
+-------------------------------------+
| '765','76','70','70','80','82','11' |
+-------------------------------------+
```